# Reading line from MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to read data from my database to find out is I inserted it correctly. However, the following code has some bug.

```
$pwdcrypt = SHA1($pwd);
$userregisterquery='INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES ('.$email.', '.$pwdcrypt.')';
echo $userregisterquery;
mysqli_query($link, $userregisterquery);

//    echo "Kantaan vietiin sähköposti: ".$email. " ja salasana: ".$pwdcrypt;

$usergetdataquery='select email, password FROM user WHERE email=\''.$email.'\'';
//echo $usergetdataquery; 
$result =  mysqli_query($link, $usergetdataquery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo "the result is:".print_r($row);
```

It outputs

```
INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES (a.a@a.com, fcf007079136b14ee9632ea2e3b1e85a061f5006)select email, password FROM user WHERE email='a.a@a.com'SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE email = 'a.a@a.com'the result is:1
```

On the other hand, as I check table in terminal, it outputs only the user id I inserted there via terminal who has different e-mail address. Why can't I see that user I inserted via WWW-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

`$userregisterquery=` ...

you forgot the quotes. It must read:

```
$userregisterquery='INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($email).'", "'.mysql_real_escape_string($pwdcrypt).'")';
```

In the line

`$usergetdataquery=`...

you have quotes, but you don't have `mysql_real_escape_string()`, so it will work but it's a security problem if `$email` comes from outside.

Comment: I think you mean mysql_real_escape_string() -- addslashes() is not secure enough.

Comment: I edited the answer. However, I don't know any attack on addslashes() as long as the connection charset is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15, as it probably is in a Finnish application.

Comment: I have the following function for security issues:     function clean_input($s) {
      $s = strip_tags($s);
      $s = stripcslashes($s);
      $s = htmlspecialchars($s);    
      return trim($s);
    }